# Search through structure of folders

Tags: javascript, search, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, directory-structure

Using Google Apps Script I need to search through a structure of folders in Google Drive. The thing is that I don't know how many levels of subfolders will be inside the main folder (take a look at the image). I'll always be looking for "file-2" but there will be a lot of "file-2" and I need to find all of them.

I don't know the name nor the ID of the subfolders.

I don't know the ID of the files "file-2" that I need to search.

I only know that there will be a main folder and I need to search for all of the files "file-2" inside.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate all folders ans subfolders, DriveApp has a [searchFiles(params) method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String)) that will return all the files with that name, no matter where they are.

example :

```
 var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(
     'title contains "file-2"');
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   Logger.log(file.getName());// file is a file object, it has methods to get parent folders if this info is useful... see same doc + links
 }
```